# pip PermissionError: [Errno 13] inside virtual environment

Tags: python, permissions, pip, python-venv

I created a virtual environment for `python3.5` using `python3 -m venv --system-site-packages <venv>`.

Now when installing packages inside the virtual environment using `pip3` I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages'
```

Why does pip want to install the packages at `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages` and not at `<venv>/lib/python3.5/site-packages`?

Comment: Have you activated your virtualenv?

Comment: yes. its name is in brackets before the bash prompt

Comment: Install with pip, do not use pip3

Comment: I tried that as well. I can just type `pip install <package name>, can I? Or do I have to indicate somehow to use a pip for my virtual environment?

Comment: It's because you used the option `--system-site-packages`. Based on the [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#the-system-site-packages-option), it says, **This can be used if you have control over the global site-packages directory, and you want to depend on the packages there. If you want isolation from the global system, do not use this flag.**

Comment: Yes. I wanted that (and I control the global directory). Just did not want to use `sudo` if not necessary. But I think i fixed it. Using `python -m pip install` istead of `pip install` does not produce the error.

Comment: I faced similar kind of problem to solve it I tried to create new virtualenv which didn't solve problem so I reconfigured PATH, pip and created new virtualenv.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you reconfigured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want pip to install the packages at `<venv>/lib/python3.5/site-packages`, please create the virtual environment by this way:

`python3 -m venv <venv>`

By the way, I usually create virtual environment as follows:

`alias venv='virtualenv --python=python3 venv'
alias actvenv='source venv/bin/activate'
venv
actvenv`

Comment: ok. so the `system-site-packages` is the cause of the problem? I have verified now that using `python -m pip install` does install in the virtual environment, whereas pip install does not in this case